# Google App Script for Forms variable

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a AppScripts code for creating an expiry date for a Google form. In the code the initial time from which the user can submit a response has to be dynamically changed depending upon the time at which the form goes live every time. This is because of the use case of the form. I can't allow the administrator to go to Script editor and change the value manually everytime he wants the Form go live.

Is there a possibility through which the date can be put in dynamically through an interface.

Here is the [link](http://www.labnol.org/internet/schedule-google-forms/20707/) from which I have taken the code.

And in this context I am talking about the variables named:

```
FORM_OPEN_DATE and FORM_CLOSE_DATE.
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a sideBar or a popup with the [Html Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#prompt_dialogs) and have a little form or prompt dialag where the user can input the variables